# Start system_server before class preloading

Tags: android

I was wondering what will happen if the system_server is started in parallel to class preloading in zygote?

I experimented with that a bit but didn't see any problem with activities getting slow. 
There is a good reason for that but I don't know why this is happening.

Can anyone share some info?

Any help is appreciated.